# Visual Studio Packages Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, conda, virtual-environment

I installed a self made package **sdm_plugin_common** into conda base. However , Visual Studio Code does not recognize the syntax, see below 
[image]

My environment is activated to conda base:

[image]

However I do not have issues when executing the code. How could I avoid this "False warning" ??

My current

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Python Analysis Engine** tends to complain about unresolved reports. Switch back to **Jedi** as IntelliSense engine.

In settings.json set:

```
"python.jediEnabled": true,
```

Comment: Did not solve my problem. It is weird because the code runs but the editor complains about the module not found

Comment: Exactly, this is an IntelliSense issue.

Comment: I don't know what you actually did and how your settings.json looks like. I just tried to help you ...

Comment: I appreciate your comment but just said that included your command under "settings.json" and nothing changed....